# How to handle Excel sheets with macros

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, excel, co-authoring

We have an Excel sheet with Macros on it. We uploaded the Excel sheet into SharePoint Document Library. When the Excel is opened using Excel Online, Macros do not work. So in order to make Macros work we have to open the Excel with client which will check out the file disabling others from performing Co-editing. Is there a way to handle macros without checking out the document? Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are not supported in Excel Online, you either need to remove the macros to allow editing in Excel Online or use the client exclusively for those files.