# How to save Excel w/Macros to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, excel-macro

Good Day,

I've reviewed the following questions [Excel Macros in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270616/excel-macros-in-sharepoint) and [How to handle Excel sheets with macros](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145962/how-to-handle-excel-sheets-with-macros) and am still stumped.

So... We have an Excel Spreadsheet that is full of macros that we are trying to save to SharePoint.  I realize now that macros are not supported by Office online, but when I open said Excel Spreadsheet in desktop app, the macros are still not working.  Where might I be going wrong here?

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated!

-Cheers!
DS

Comment: What error message do you get? You should get a warning to trust the location, after that the macros should work fine...

Comment: You might also have to add your sharepoint URL to the trusted location of office settings

Comment: Thank you @RuneSperre do you know how I would do this as an admin for all users?  Also, I don't get a pop up at all, it just doesn't run the macros.

Comment: Group policy, but you should be able to do it for yourself to test: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/privacy/manage-privacy-controls